# Disable form validation in lLaravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Hi I'm completely new to **Laravel**. I have a problem validating the form in *booking system*.
What I need is I don't want the email to be required when user enters the inputs in **email fields**. I tried removing `required` in form, but no success. Here's the code for email field. I know they're using **bootstrap** for this.

```
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Email</label>
                 <input type="email" class="form-control required" name="email" id="booking_email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="formData.email"/>
             </div>
         </div>
```

and in the **popup** , it shows

> Whoops! There were some problems. The email field is required.

Here's the booking controller code for form validation

```
   public function saveBooking(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone_no' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: I see you are using Angular in the field. Did you check your angular code? Is it doing any validation for email there?  Edit: Oh, I thought you removed the `required` from the validation rule. Seems you removed it only from the form field. You should delete it from the controller validation rule also.

Comment: change the validation rule to email => 'sometimes|email'

Comment: ya tried that too, but does nothing. The messages is gone but when I submit the form, it stays on that very page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your validation rules:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
        'phone_no' => 'required',
    ]);
```

In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array.

> [Check This Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Comment: Tried that. When I submit button , it does nothing. The page just freezes. And when I check  console, it shows error message
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500**

Comment: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: can you post all your code inside the controller saveBooking method

Comment: Are you using ajax? $.post('/save', {
      "_token": // put token here,
      "email": $("#bookingEmail").val()
    }

Comment: *Here's the code for form**
https://gist.github.com/prabin04/f93e3b3776e7a2ee81b3

Comment: $.post('/route', { _token: $('.contentpanel').find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val(),    ...try that on your code $('#check').on('click'...

Comment: {{ csrf_token() }} change to $('.contentpanel').find( 'input[name=_token]' ).val()

Comment: I thought you are running in a form sorry. can you add this on html <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >

Comment: you mean just below the email address field or anywhere inside the form.

Comment: anywhere in the form make sure it is inside the contentpanel class div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106198/discussion-between-prabin-parajuli-and-goper-leo-zosa).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `required` from your validation in the controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'email',
            'phone_no' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Also, as @GoperLeoZosa mentioned, you can add `'email' => 'email|sometimes|required'`.

This would validate the field only if the `email` field is present in the array.

Comment: Tried that. When I submit button , it does nothing. The page just freezes. And when I check  console, it shows error message
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500**

Comment: Check for the `CSRF token` in your form if you are using Ajax.

Comment: Are there other files too I need to change ??

Comment: Do you have a `csrf_token` field in your form?

Comment: Yes.. it goes like this

        ``var itemsInTable = $('#user-booking').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            'ajax': {
                "type": 'POST',
                'url' : '/booking/list',
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
                    d.date = $("#datepicker").val();
                    d.vehicle_id = $("#vehicle_id").val();
                }
            }``

Comment: Can you inspect your network tab and click on the error preview tab and see whats the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106190/discussion-between-prabin-parajuli-and-jilson-thomas).